# Error: Builder TemplateDefinitionBuilder doesn't support animations yet

Tags: angular

Getting this when enabling Ivy in angular 6.0.3 - any workarounds? Tried removing animations/browser animation references to no avail...

Error: Builder TemplateDefinitionBuilder doesn't support animations yet

Answer (score 1):

Ivy is not yet released and seems there are no work arounds as of now with angular:6.0.9

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24112

Check the current status on angular ivy here.
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/render3/STATUS.md